# magento illegal block type

Tags: magento, exception

I have a problem with my magento 1.7.0.1 shop system and get the following exception.
I hope somebody can help.

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Ungültiger Blocktyp: '
>   in /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/app/Mage.php:594
>   Stack trace:
>
> /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495):
>   Mage::throwException('Ung??ltiger Blo...')
>   /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('', Array)
>   /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', 'product.info.up...')
>   /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', 'product.info.up...')
>   /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element),
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>   /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
>   /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
>   /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(73):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
>   /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/View.php(144):
>   Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->initProductLayout(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product),
>   Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController))
>   /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php(132):
>   Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_View->prepareAndRender(2206,
>   Object(Mage_Catalog_ProductController), Object(Varien_Object))
>   /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419):
>   Mage_Catalog_ProductController->viewAction()
>   /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
>   /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>   /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354):
>   Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>   /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/app/Mage.php(683):
>   Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>   /is/htdocs/wp1162418_SSTJ4PVTRV/www/magento-shop/index.php(87):
>   Mage::run('', 'store') {main}

Comment: Hi, I don't want to scare you away but besides this site there is also [magento](http://magento.stackexchange.com/) dedicated to this. Can you add when and where you get this error? That helps in diagnosing. Also notice that in general 'thanks' etc can be left out. Thanking works with voting on all StackExchnage sites.

Comment: It looks like something to do with your upsell block on the product view page. Check your template files (catalog.xml) and ensure you have a block type set for the block definition with name product.info.upsell. To establish if this is where you error originates you could comment out the line `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products'); ?>` in view.phtml and the xml definitions for the block mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

i just realized that i have the same error on my installation (also 1.7.0.2)

it happens on the product view page.

But i found the error/a solution. in
/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/factfinder.xml

replace

```
`<block name="product.info.upsell">`
```

with

```
 `<block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">`
```

and the error is gone

Comment: This is the solution! Thank you! It happened to me with Magento 1.9.3.4.